# Is there a way to run a single PSQL Aggregate Function without hitting a database table?

Tags: postgresql

For example, I'd like to run:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE("What's My Name?", "[^a-z0-9_\-]", "-");
```

and simply see what it returns, instead of doing a search against a DB Table. I tried to run it in the CLI and got

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REGEXP_REPLACE"
LINE 1: REGEXP_REPLACE("What's My Name?", "[^a-z0-9_\-]", "-")
```

(I'm trying to be generic- I'd like to be able to use this for other PSQL Aggregate Functions as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, this is SQL, so every output you get is a relation. Hence to calculate the result of a function, you need to run `SELECT` to retrieve the function's value.

Unfortunately, in many DBs, `SELECT` requires a table. In Oracle land, there's [`dual`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) to work around this problem:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('What''s My Name?', '[^a-z0-9_\-]', '-') FROM dual;
```

PostgreSQL, however, allows you to execute a `SELECT` query without having to specify a table:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('What''s My Name?', '[^a-z0-9_\-]', '-');
```

Note that the *string* quote in SQL is `'`, not `"`. PostgreSQL uses double quotes to quote identifiers.

Side note: Not every function is an aggregate. An aggregate is a function that combines multiple values into a single output value. `REGEXP_REPLACE()` is just a normal [string function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: Thank you! I come from Rails land, and they do their best to do as little SQL as possible, so I'm pretty noob-ish when it comes down to actually using `psql` syntax. That's doing exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to run a single PSQL Aggregate Function without hitting a database table?

Yes, in PostgreSQL you can write a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` part at all.